# Sending Catalogue WhatsApp Business API

Tags: django, whatsapi

I am trying to ingrate integrate WhatsaApp Business API. I have setup the webhook and can now receive messages through the webhook but when when I send a catalogue, the webhook says `Message type is currently not supported.`Below is the full response

```
{
    'object': 'whatsapp_business_account',
    'entry': [
        {
            'id': '**********************',
            'changes': [
                {
                    'value': {
                        'messaging_product': 'whatsapp',
                        'metadata': {
                            'display_phone_number': '***************',
                            'phone_number_id': ''***************'
                        },
                        'contacts': [
                            {
                                'profile': {
                                    'name': 'Majesty'
                                },
                                'wa_id': 'Majesty'
                            }
                        ],
                        'messages': [
                            {
                                'from': ''***************',
                                'id': 'wamid.'***************==',
                                'timestamp': ''***************',
                                'errors': [
                                    {
                                        'code': ******,
                                        'title': 'Message type unknown',
                                        'message': 'Message type unknown',
                                        'error_data': {
                                            'details': 'Message type is currently not supported.'
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                'type': 'unsupported'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    'field': 'messages'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to send catalogue receive it through the webhook